# How to get better performance with Qt4.5 on arm platform

Tags: performance, qt, user-interface, embedded-linux, porting

I just finished porting the QT4.5.3 GUI lib with touchscreen lib tslib1.4.1 to arm9 based S3C2440;but I find programs are running slow.How to make Qt4.5.3 run more smoothly?
I have already read the references on http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7-snapshot/fine-tuning-features.html and http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7-snapshot/qt-performance.html  Any other suggestion according to your experience?Thanks！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the S3C24xx too. I use Qt 4.6.2. Here is my compile configuration

```
@host:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2#./configure \
-opensource \
-confirm-license \
-release -shared \
-embedded arm \
-xplatform qws/linux-arm-g++ \
-depths 16,18,24 \
-fast \
-optimized-qmake \
-pch \
-qt-sql-sqlite \
-qt-libjpeg \
-qt-zlib \
-qt-libpng \
-qt-freetype \
-little-endian -host-little-endian \
-no-qt3support \
-no-libtiff -no-libmng \
-no-opengl \
-no-mmx -no-sse -no-sse2 \
-no-3dnow \
-no-openssl \
-no-webkit \
-no-qvfb \
-no-phonon \
-no-nis \
-no-opengl \
-no-cups \
-no-glib \
-no-xcursor -no-xfixes -no-xrandr -no-xrender \
-no-separate-debug-info \
-nomake examples -nomake tools -nomake docs \
-qt-mouse-tslib -I/usr/local/tslib/include -L/usr/local/tslib/lib

@host:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2# make
@host:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2# make install
```

Also notice that, if you change optimization level of compiler in file qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/mkspecs/common/g++.conf from -O2 to -O0 may cause the Qt library run very slow. 
Hope it is useful for you.

Comment: How smoothly your qt runs?My app,including demos provided by qt,runs slowly on S3C2440.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?3gqq7vc16bu1ngx this is my compiled Qt, it runs quite good in my case sir. You also need to configure some environment variables in .bashrc file (it is here http://www.mediafire.com/?oi3hyx6vmlscbxp)

Comment: I run my app via NFS server on PC, this may result in the slow performance due to the networking process.Do you use NFS?

Comment: I use both NFS and NAND rootfs. If you doubt about your network connection. Connect the board directly to your NFS server and test again. If it does not work again, maybe problem comes from the software

Answer (score 0):

I suggest running a profiling tool to see what your program is actually doing. It might be that another part of your program is hogging the CPU. Performance problems are often first noticed through the GUI since it is something that the user sees and interacts with. [Oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/) is a good tool to try out.